# Удаление файла с сервера

Tags: php

У меня есть на сервере файл, а как его с помощью php удалить?

Comment: [Очень сложный запрос][1]


  [1]: https://www.google.com.ua/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+delete+file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в закладки парочку поисковых систем!

---

Функция [unlink("filename.txt");](http://www.php.su/unlink())